# Mock spring's LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean method using Mockito?

Tags: java, spring, unit-testing, mockito

I am trying to write unit testcases for the below code and am trying to mock the EntityManager implementation. I am unable to do so and I get null entity manager bean in my test class.

```
public List<Object[]> getForecastResults(String query, String siteId, long startTime, long endTimestamp)
{   
    List<Object[]> result = null;
    EntityManager em = null;
    try {           
        query = String.format(query, startTime, endTimestamp, siteId);
        logger.debug(" Query : " + query);
        em = localContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.nativeEntityManagerFactory.createEntityManager();
        EntityTransaction et = em.getTransaction();
        et.begin();
        result = (List<Object[]>) em.createNativeQuery(query).getResultList();
        //logger.debug("Results from the query : " + query + " are :" + Utility.toJsonString(result, true));
    } catch (Exception ex) {            
        ex.printStackTrace();
        logger.error("Error Occurred while fetching the data for the query : " + query);            
    }           
    return result;
}
```

The test code I have written to mock it is below:

```
@InjectMocks
    private LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean emMock = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
```

...

```
Mockito.when(localContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.nativeEntityManagerFactory.createEntityManager()).thenReturn();
```

I should return a list when this is called as output So i need the whole method to be mocked. Please help !

Comment: @InjectMocks will try to injects in the LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean its dependencies, however there is not defined any other bean, doesn't know what to inject.

Comment: Instead of mocking the `LocalContainerEntityManager` fix your code to be proper so that you don't have to mock it. Your code is flawed.

Answer (score 2):

First off all instead of `@InjectMocks` you should be using `@Mock` and put the `@InjectMocks` on the class you are trying to unit test.

However the fact that you are even considering mocking the `LocalContainterEntityManagerFactoryBean` is a sign that your code is flawed. You shouldn't be using the `LCEMFB` in code. It is only for configuration. It is a `FactoryBean` that creates an `EntityManagerFactory` so actually you should be injecting an `EntityManagerFactory` into your code which you should be mocking.

Instead of wiring the `LCEMFB` use the plain `EMF` and get an instance by annotating the field with `@PersistenceUnit`.

```
@PersistenceUnit
private EntityManagerFactory emf;
```

Then your method is also a bit cleaner

```
public List<Object[]> getForecastResults(String query, String siteId, long startTime, long endTimestamp)
{   
    List<Object[]> result = null;
    EntityManager em = null;
    try {           
        query = String.format(query, startTime, endTimestamp, siteId);
        logger.debug(" Query : " + query);
        em = emf.createEntityManager();
        EntityTransaction et = em.getTransaction();
        et.begin();
        result = (List<Object[]>) em.createNativeQuery(query).getResultList();
        //logger.debug("Results from the query : " + query + " are :" + Utility.toJsonString(result, true));
    } catch (Exception ex) {            
        ex.printStackTrace();
        logger.error("Error Occurred while fetching the data for the query : " + query);            
    }           
    return result;
}
```

However what you actually should be doing is injecting an `EntityManager` and don't try to create one yourself (your code is still flawed as you aren't closing the transaction nor the created `EntityManager` which in turn will eventually lead you to being unable to connect to your database as the underlying `Connection` remains open as well.

So instead of injecting either the `LCEMFB` or a `EMF` use a plain `EntityManager` instead and let spring manage it for you. To have spring manage the transaction make sure there is an `@EnableTransactionManagement` or `<tx:annotation-driven />` in your configuration else it won't work.

```
@PersistenceContext
private EntityManager em;
```

Now your method is really focussed on what it should do, get data from the database.

```
@Transactional(readOnly=true)
public List<Object[]> getForecastResults(String query, String siteId, long startTime, long endTimestamp) {   
    query = String.format(query, startTime, endTimestamp, siteId);
    return em.createNativeQuery(query).getResultList();
}
```

Now in your test you should only need to mock the `EntityManager`.

All of this is also explained in the [ORM chapter](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/orm.html#orm-jpa-straight) of the Spring Reference guide.

Another thing that worries me is that you are using a String and parsing that to be used as a query. This is potentially dangerous and a cause for [SQL injection attacks](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/SQL_Injection_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet). Instead of doing the formatting yourself you should let it be handled by Hibernate or JDBC.

```
@Transactional(readOnly=true)
public List<Object[]> getForecastResults(String query, String siteId, long startTime, long endTimestamp) {   
    query = String.format(query, startTime, endTimestamp, siteId);
    Query q = em.createNativeQuery(query);
    q.setParameter("siteId", siteId)
     .setParameter("startTime", startTime)
     .setParameter("endTime", endTimestamp);
    return q.getResultList();
}
```

The code above assumes a query in the form of `SELECT * FROM YOURTABLE WHERE siteId=:siteId and startTime >= :startTime and endTime <= :endTime` (or whatever your SQL looks like).